# Simple groovy program - Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I created a very simple gradle file with a task called groovy.

```
task groovy << {}

println "Hello Groovy!"
```

I try to run it under my project's folder in cmd(I am using Windows 8.1) as

```
gradle groovy
```

but I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
 Task 'groovy' not found in root project 'MyExercise'.

 Try:
 Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace    
 option
 to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log    
 output
```

Why can it not find the groovy task? It is declared in my `build.gradle` file. Gradle is installed. Here is my version.

```
Gradle 3.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-08-15 13:15:01 UTC
Revision:     ad76ba00f59ecb287bd3c037bd25fc3df13ca558

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02)
OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
```

and the command gradle tasks shows:

```
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared
t 'MyExercise'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'MyE
ubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependenc
ect 'MyExercise'.
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'MyExerci
ng]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'MyExercise'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'MyExercise'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'MyExercise'

To see all tasks and more detail, run gradle tasks --all

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Theo.

Comment: And what does `gradle tasks` show you?

Comment: I put the result of gradle tasks in my question

Comment: I think I should see something like Other Tasks groovy..But I don't:(

Comment: Just tried with a `build.gradle` _exactly_ as you describe, and I see the `groovy` task under `Other Tasks` when I type `gradle tasks`...  Something else you haven't mentioned must be messing things up

Comment: Honestly I don't know what it could be wrong. I also have Android Studio which uses Gradle 2.10  installed with my Android apps in it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly your file is not named `build.gradle`  If this is the case then gradle won't know what the task `groovy` is since it didn't read that file.

If you want to specify a file other than `build.gradle` for evaluation by gradle then you need to give gradle the file name.  For clarity I used a file named `test.groovy` and showed how to execute a task in the groovy file.

```
~/temp/39294812 $ cat test.groovy 
task groovy << {
    println "Hello to you!"
}

println "Hello groovy"

~/temp/39294812 $ gradle -q -b test.groovy groovy
Hello groovy
Hello to you!
```

Also note if you just need to add your task to another `build.gradle` you could use `apply from: <path>`

```
// to call groovy from inside a `build.gradle` file
apply from: 'test.groovy'
```

Comment: Yes I made it. In fact I forgot to put the code inside the gradle file. haha.